# How to convert Likert scale responses to numerical in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I sent out a Google Form questionnaire and in select questions I used Likert scale. How best do I convert it to numerical so it can be useful in logistic regression that I want to try? The other columns I already converted to numerical via replace function. My data set now looks like this:

| Data | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Somewhat Agree | Neutral | Somewhat Disagree | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | Strongly Agree | Strongly Disagree | Neutral | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | Neutral | Somewhat Agree | Strongly Disagree | 2 |

Would need help please in the Python codes to effectively convert Q2 to Q4 into numerical, as in truth I have around 15 of these type of columns.

Comment: That's a straightforward value replacement.  I don't understand where  you're stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace) and a replacer `dict`:

```
replacer = {'Strongly Disagree': 1, 'Somewhat Disagree': 2,
            'Neutral': 3,
            'Somewhat Agree': 4, 'Strongly Agree': 5}

# Select String Columns
cols = df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object']
# Replace Values in those Columns
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(replacer)
```

`df`:

```
   Data  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5
0     1   0   4   3   2   3
1     2   3   5   1   3   1
2     3   1   3   4   1   2
```

---

Alternatives Selection Options:

[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) with slicing:

```
df.loc[:, 'Q2':'Q4'] = df.loc[:, 'Q2':'Q4'].replace(replacer)
```

Explicit Column Selection:

```
cols = ['Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(replacer)
```